# Problemas con Session CakePHP

Tags: php, jquery, session, cakephp-bake

Estimados buenas tardes, quisiera comentar un problema que tengo en base a un sistema desarrollado en cakephp versión 2.4:

Resulta que por algún motivo o razón CakePHP elimina las sesiones sin motivo alguno, revise el controlador, js, html y todo esta correcto.

No es primera vez que desarrollo sistemas en cake, ya son varios , llevo años en el tema pero esto es primera vez que me ocurre y ya agote todas las instancias, al momento de realizar el login esta ok, autentica y genera el login correctamente con el componente de Session Aauth , pero, cada ves que navego por el sistema me cierra la sesión y me saca del sistema.

El problema es que el log no muestra nada, ningún error y no solo destruye la session de login, si no que destruye todas las sesiones (carro u otras).

Realice cambios en el core,php ,cambie el Security level a "low", cambien el timeout de Session, habilite el checkAgent y autoRegenerate y aun asi sigo teniendo problemas, la vedad ya no se que mas hacer.

Agradecería enormemente algún comentario o alguien que me pueda ayudar un poco con esto.

Comment: Sería bueno si podrías juntar data acerca de despues de cuanto tiempo la sesión expira y como eso no conforme con tu configuración y el tiempo esperado,

Answer (score 1):

Algo similiar me había sucedido hace tiempo y, después de muchas vueltas, me di cuenta de que se trataba de un problema sobre el dominio. Al desarrollar varias aplicaciones sobre el mismo dominio, la cookie de sesión en el navegador falla (aunque tengan diferente nombre).

¿Es ese tu problema? Solventarlo puede ser sencillo creando un subdominio para cada nuevo proyecto.

Por otro lado, también podrías revisar la gestión de la sesión desde el archivo de **core** del directorio **config** y pasar del uso de cake a php:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'cookie' => 'nombre_de_la_cookie',
    'timeout' => 'tiempo_de_vida',
    'cookieTimeout'=> 'tiempo_de_vida'
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Mira tenia el mismo problema en la misma version, y lo solucione con esto cambiando en core.php 
Utilizo la session de cake, y acordate de poner los permisos de escritura y lectura a la carpeta tmp. Con esto solucione todos mis problemas. Saludos

```
    Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults'=>'cake', 
    'cookie'=>'algunnombre',
    'timeout' => 9000, // The session will timeout after 30 minutes of inactivity
    'cookieTimeout' => 4567, // The session cookie will live for at most 24 hours, this does not effect session timeouts
    'checkAgent' => false,
    //'autoRegenerate' => true, // causes the session expiration time to reset on each page load
));
```